# Measure CPU usage of a process and all it's subprocesses

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm creating a new process `A` using `multiprocessing.Process`, and `A` may fork/spawn new processes `B,C,D...`, B/C/D can also fork/spawn new processes `E,F,G...`

Now I want to measure the overall cpu usage of process `A` and all it's children/grandchildren (snapshot of the overall cpu usage at certain time), how can I do it in python?

Answer (score 2):

[psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#process-class) has `psutil.Process.children(recursive=True)` API, so we can do:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import psutil

p = mp.Process(target=some_func,args=(arg1,arg2))
p.start()
while p.pid is None:
  time.sleep(0.1)
p_obj = psutil.Process(p.pid)
cpu_usage = p_obj.cpu_percent(interval=1)
for child in p_obj.children(recursive=True)
  cpu_usage += child.cpu_percent(interval=1)
print(cpu_usage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use psutil library and it has current_process.cpu_percent(interval=interval), change interval accodingly. Keep this in function and call it with multiprocessing.Process(target=function).

By this way, you can monitor all processes that you create with multiprocessing

Comment: I don't have access for code in `A`, so I can't simply insert `current_process.cpu_percent()` in all subprocesses